# mysql multiple not operator for single column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, operators

Please how to MySql SELECT with multiple NOT operation for single column ?

```
Example:-

WHERE column != 'a' column != 'b' column != 'c'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use something with `NOT IN()`

```
WHERE column NOT IN ('a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing `AND`

```
WHERE column != 'a' AND column != 'b' AND column != 'c'
```